# How do you define different root routes depending if a user is logged in or not in rails 4.2 (not using devise)?

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have created a working User system of logging in, logging out, signing up a new user etc by defining helper methods in the application_controller file. I have defined the root path as users#new (signup form) in my routes.rb file. when a user is logged in i want the root of the application to be a different controller and action. when a user is logged in and they go to the root route, i want it to take them to post#index BUT still have the root url in the url bar in the browser. I am working in rails 4.2.

I have searched for hours and cant find an answer that works...

(NOT USING DEVISE)

Comment: Add filters to redirect the user based on whether he is signed in or not.

Comment: but by redirecting the user, it changes the url. I want the url to just be www.*website*.com when the user is logged in AND logged out, but show different pages

Comment: Then you should add two partials and render it based on the condition in the view.